# gfortran compile errors Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm writing Fortran code to input user subroutine in Abaqus.
This example code for UEL example.

I want to make UEL subroutine for hyperelasticity parameters.
I'm first doing Fortran, so I could not solve the errors.

This is my code.
Error is Unclassifiable statement,
but I don't know Fortran method.

```
    c
c Blankholder force contro element for deep drawing applications
c
     subroutine uel(rhs, amatrx, svars, energy, ndofel, nrhs, nsvars,
    1 props, nprops, coords, mcrd, nnode, u, du, v, a, jtype, time, dtime,
    2 kstep, kinc, jelem, params, nload, jdltyp, adlmag, predef, npredf,
    3 lfoags, mlvarx, ddlmag, mdload, pnewdt, jprops, njprop, period)
c
     include 'aba_param.inc'
c
     dimension rhs(mlvarx, *), amatrx(ndofel, ndofel), svars(*), props(*),
    1 energy(7), coord(mcrd, nnode), u(ndofel), du(mlvarx, *), v(ndofel),
    2 a(ndofel), time(2), params(*), jdltyp(mdload, *), adlmag(mdload, *),
    4 ddlag(mdload, *), predef(2, npredf, nnode), lflags(4), jprops(*)
c
c Pick up the input data
c
     sPunch         = props(1)      !Spring stiffness
     fPunchTarget = props(2)        ! Target punch force
     fHolderInit    = props(3)      ! Initial blankholder force
     fractHolder   = props(4)       ! Fractional change allowed
     tolPunch       = props(5)      ! Tolereance on punch force
c
c Calculate the punch force
c
     fPunchNew = sPunch * (u(1)-u(2))
c
c Generate force vector and
c
     rhs(1,1) = -fPunchNew
     rhs(2,1) = +fpunchNew
c
c Generate stiffness matris
c
     amatrx(1,1) = +sPunch
     amatrx(1,2) = -sPunch
     amatrx(2,1) = -sPunch
c
c The holder force is only applied during steps 2 and 3
c
     if(kstep.eq.2) teh
c
c Ramp the punch force to the desired starting value
c
    fHolder = time(1)*fHolderInit/period
    svars(2) = fHolder
    rhs(3,1) = -fHolder
    else if(kstep.eq.3) then
c
c Adjust the punch force to control the blankholder force
c
c Values of state variables at start of increment
c
    fPunchOld = svars(1)    !Punch force
    fHolderOld = svars(2)   !Blankholder force
    fPunchMax = svar(3) !Maximum blankholder force
c
c Allowed change in blankholer force
c
    dfHolderMax = fractHolder * fHolderOld
c
c Allowed tolerance in the targetforce
c
    dfPunchTol = tolPunch * fPunchTarget
c
c Calculate the holder force
c
    if (fPunchOld.gt.fPunchTarget+dfPunchTol) then
      fHolerNew = fHolderOld - dfHolderMax  !Decrease
    else if(fPunchMax.lt.fPunchTarget+dfPunchTol .or.
     1      fPunchOld.gt.fPunchTarget-dfPunchTol) then
      fHolderNew = fHolderOld
    else
      fHolderNew = fHolderOld + dfHolderMax !Increase
    end if
c
c Generate holer force vector
c
    rhs(3,1) = -fHolderNew
c
c Update state variables
c
    svars(1) = fPunchNew
    svars(2) = fPHolderNew
    svars(3) = max(fPunchMax, fPunchNew)
     end if
c
     return 
     end
```

And this is my errors.

```
my_subroutine.for:4:6:

      subroutine uel(rhs, amatrx, svars, energy, ndofel, nrhs, nsvars,
      1
Error: Bad continuation line at (1)
my_subroutine.for:4:6:

      subroutine uel(rhs, amatrx, svars, energy, ndofel, nrhs, nsvars,
      1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
my_subroutine.for:5:6:

     1 props, nprops, coords, mcrd, nnode, u, du, v, a, jtype, time, dtime,
      1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
my_subroutine.for:6:6:

     2 kstep, kinc, jelem, params, nload, jdltyp, adlmag, predef, npredf,
      1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
my_subroutine.for:7:6:

     3 lfoags, mlvarx, ddlmag, mdload, pnewdt, jprops, njprop, period)
      1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
aba_param.inc:17:57:

       PARAMETER(IALLD=0,IRMMD=4,NEMPTY=0,ISPIND=2,IGRAD=0)
                                                         1
Error: Unexpected characters in PARAMETER statement at (1)
my_subroutine.for:12:6:

     1 energy(7), coord(mcrd, nnode), u(ndofel), du(mlvarx, *), v(ndofel),
      1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
my_subroutine.for:13:6:

     2 a(ndofel), time(2), params(*), jdltyp(mdload, *), adlmag(mdload, *),
      1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
my_subroutine.for:14:6:

     4 ddlag(mdload, *), predef(2, npredf, nnode), lflags(4), jprops(*)
      1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
my_subroutine.for:46:6:

  svars(2) = fHolder
      1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
my_subroutine.for:47:6:

  rhs(3,1) = -fHolder
      1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
my_subroutine.for:48:5:

     else if(kstep.eq.3) then
     1
Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
my_subroutine.for:48:5:

     else if(kstep.eq.3) then
     1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
my_subroutine.for:79:6:

  rhs(3,1) = -fHolderNew
      1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
my_subroutine.for:83:11: Error: 'svars' at (1) is not a variable
my_subroutine.for:84:11: Error: 'svars' at (1) is not a variable
my_subroutine.for:85:11: Error: 'svars' at (1) is not a variable
f951.exe: Error: Unexpected end of file in 'my_subroutine.for'
```

How can I solve this error and use Fortran method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using so-called "fixed-form" Fortran with lines continuation signaled by a character in the 6th column, see the [Fortran Wiki page about this](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fixed+form+layout).

From the error, you apparently miss one space on every beginning of line (the error is at character 6 of the line), provided the formatting in the question is correct.

Make sure that the "continuation character" (here, the 1, 2 and 3) are on the sixth column.

You can also decide to switch to "free form" Fortran in which continuation lines are indicated differently.